# upgrading to grails 4: spring security inerceptUrlMap doesn't wortk based on hierarchy

Tags: grails, spring-security

The interceptUrLMap seems to only whitelist urls if the roles match exactly and not based on the hierarchy.

```
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.roleHierarchy = '''
   ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN>ROLE_ADMIN
 '''
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
     [pattern:"/admin/**",access:['ROLE_ADMIN']]
 ]
```

If I log in as super admin I get blocked.
However if I log in as a regular admin I am allowed to access the admin section.

Answer (score 0):

The roleHierarchy value is whitespace sensitive now.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.roleHierarchy = '''
   ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN>ROLE_ADMIN
'''
```

should be

```
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.roleHierarchy = '''
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN > ROLE_ADMIN
  '''
```